# Problems upgrading to 16.04 from windows 10

Tags: windows, 16.04

I have a Toshiba satellite laptop that came preinstalled with Windows 7 then I had it upgraded to Windows 10. I decided to upgrade to 16.04. So I made a bootable USB and set my boot order accordingly. It booted straight to Windows. So I redownlaoded it and tried again with the same result. Next I made a bootable disk and the same thing happened. Has anybody run into this problem before and is there a workaround? I know that wubi isn't supposed to work for W10. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there seems to be an issue if you are using uefi .. I found when booting my PC from a USB i needed to make sure that the USB stick was plugged into a USB 2.0 port then I had two options for booting to it... just a normal one and a UEFI one ... if i chose the normal one it would boot to it ... if i chose the UEFI one it would just go straight into Windows.. this may be your issue .. not sure if you are dealing with UEFI tho

Comment: In my case I can press 'f12' on booting and it will take me to a 'one time boot menu' where i can select which device to boot from (internal HD, USB stick, CD/DVD drive). Windows is quite likely to be using UEFI to boot, so select to boot the USB stick from the UEFI Boot Options. Let us know if that works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: maybe also useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

At boot, open your boot menu (usually f2 or escape), and select "cd-rom device" or something like that.

Good luck, I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Fast startup and hibernation in Windows - so boot into Windows - open command prompt as administrator and execute : `powercfg /h off`. Open Windows Control Panel, go to the Power Settings and uncheck Fast startup. Shutdown the PC completely - do NOT reboot.
Boot into BIOS and select the Ubuntu installation USB drive you created marked with UEFI in front to boot from.